# Triggering php from html

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP world. In my html page I am passing some variable using GET method to my php file.
This php file exist in the same directory where my html file is. But on triggering the action by clicking the submit Button in the html file I am not able to trigger the php file(php file is not displaying the html format)

If I replace ACTION=”some_file.php”  to ACTION=”some_file.html” the html file is getting open.What's going wrong here.
I am using wamp stack.

Thnx,
Kaushik

Comment: Can you post example code of file some_file.php ?

Comment: :) try "font-size" instead of "font- si ze"

Answer (score 1):

First try to open some_file.php manually to see if PHP works fine, ex:

http://localhost/some_file.php

Comment: Guys there is no syntax problem as per i know. Problem here is in triggering php file. Yes i can open my file on direct access. http://localhost/php/sports.php  :You ’ve indicated that you like
Notice: Undefined index: Sport in C:\wamp\www\php\sports.php on line 12
!                                                                <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A GET method example, part 2</TITLE>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!-- BODY  {font- si ze: 24pt; }
-->
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>You ’ve indicated that you like
<?php echo $_GET['Sport'];?>! </P>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: I am passing the $_GET value from other html file from where i am calling this php file.

Comment: the issue is that using action, when submitting,redirects you from your html page to the php script, that is why you don't see your html content after submiting ;)

Comment: But i was expecting the new html with following details :          You’ ve indicated that you like <Variable I pass from html>

Comment: Then you really need to give us some code in your question :)

Comment: test.html:<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A GET method example, part 1</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM ACTION="sports.php" METHOD="GET">
<P>Choose your favorite sport:</P><BR/>
<SELECT NAME="Sport">
<OPTION VALUE="Baseball" >Baseball</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="Basketball">Basketball</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="Football">Football</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="IceHockey">IceHockey</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="Racing">AutoRacing</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="Soccer">Soccer</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<P><INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Submit" VALUE="Select"></P>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: sports.php: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A GET method example, part 2</TITLE>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!-- BODY  {font- si ze: 24pt; }
-->
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>You ’ve indicated that you like
<?php echo $_GET['Sport'];?>! </P>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Answer (score 0):

Try some lecturing :) http://apptools.com/phptools/forms/forms1.php

For your example try writing the html in the php file so you have the test.php file like this:

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST['buttonPressed']){
    // process form info here
}

?>

<html>
   <form action="test.php">
       <!-- some other inputs here -->
       <input type="submit" name="buttonPressed" value="Submit me"/>
   </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The authoritative reference for PHP is http://www.php.net/manual/en/ It is a bit much to wade through at once, but it's something you'll probably end up going back to over and over.

For now check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp for an intro to basic php form handling.

Good luck!

Comment: @Karpie his answer was not completly on topic but what's wrong with w3schools? That's where I started from 5 years ago...

Comment: That's exactly it, it hasn't been updated since then, and didn't feature good information even then. W3Schools is a horrible place to learn anything.

Comment: Thanks guys it is working now. I missed ./file.php I was expecting php will take by default the local path. Which it is not,so on mentioning the full path it is working fine.